# Refresh Button in Jtable

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am making a ui in which i read data from text file to JTable ,user can edit in JTable and then save the data to another text file.I want a refresh button so that if user edits in JTable and does not want the changes to be made,can click the refresh button and the data will be the previous data read from the text file.

Here is the Code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Bb extends JFrame
{
 private JTable table;
 private DefaultTableModel model;

 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
 public Bb()
 {

      String aLine ;
      Vector columnNames = new Vector();
      Vector data = new Vector();

      try
      {
           FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test1.txt");
           BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));


           StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");

           while( st1.hasMoreTokens() )
           {
                columnNames.addElement(st1.nextToken());
           }


           while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null)
           {
                StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(aLine, " ");
                Vector row = new Vector();

                while(st2.hasMoreTokens())
                {
                     row.addElement(st2.nextToken());
                }
                data.addElement( row );
           }
           br.close();
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }

      final JTable table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames){
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Override
  public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
       return Integer.class;
       }
  });


  JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
      getContentPane().add( scrollPane );


      JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
      getContentPane().add( buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH );


      JButton button1 = new JButton( "Save" );
      buttonPanel.add( button1 );
      button1.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
      {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               if  ( table.isEditing() )
                {
                     int row = table.getEditingRow();
                     int col = table.getEditingColumn();
                     table.getCellEditor(row, col).stopCellEditing();
                }

                int rows = table.getRowCount();
                int columns = table.getColumnCount();



     try { 
       StringBuilder con = new StringBuilder();
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
          for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
           {
              Object Value = table.getValueAt (i, j);
              con.append(" ");
              con.append(Value);
           }
          con.append("\r\n");
        }

    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("new.txt"));

    fileWriter.write(con.toString());
    fileWriter.flush();

   }  catch (Exception ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }
  });

      JButton button3 = new JButton( "Refresh" );
      buttonPanel.add( button3 );
      button3.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
      {
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {

           }
      });
  }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
      Bb Re = new Bb();
      Re.setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      Re.pack();
      Re.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

text File:

```
a b c d e f e
78 12 12 45 45 45 78
45 45 69 56 78 56 23
45 89 76 42 15 36 23
```

Comment: you can store them in variables before user edit or you can read text file again

Comment: Pretty much what @getlost said, but other than that I don't really see a question here.  Voting to close as 'unclear'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class Bb extends JFrame {
private JTable table;
private DefaultTableModel model;
Vector columnNames = new Vector();
Vector data = new Vector();

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Bb() {

    String aLine;

    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("test1.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fin));

        StringTokenizer st1 = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine(), " ");

        while (st1.hasMoreTokens()) {
            columnNames.addElement(st1.nextToken());
        }

        while ((aLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer st2 = new StringTokenizer(aLine, " ");
            Vector row = new Vector();
            while (st2.hasMoreTokens()) {
                row.addElement(st2.nextToken());
            }
            data.addElement(row);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    table = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(getDefaultData(), columnNames) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    });

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
    getContentPane().add(scrollPane);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("Save");
    buttonPanel.add(button1);
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (table.isEditing()) {
                int row = table.getEditingRow();
                int col = table.getEditingColumn();
                table.getCellEditor(row, col).stopCellEditing();
            }

            int rows = table.getRowCount();
            int columns = table.getColumnCount();

            try {
                StringBuilder con = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                        Object Value = table.getValueAt(i, j);
                        con.append(" ");
                        con.append(Value);
                    }
                    con.append("\r\n");
                }

                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(new File("new.txt"));

                fileWriter.write(con.toString());
                fileWriter.flush();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    JButton button3 = new JButton("Refresh");
    buttonPanel.add(button3);
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            refresh();
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bb Re = new Bb();
    Re.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Re.pack();
    Re.setVisible(true);
}

private void refresh() {

    DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(getDefaultData(),
            columnNames) {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
            return Integer.class;
        }
    };
    table.setModel(dtm);
    table.revalidate();
}

private Vector getDefaultData() {
    Vector defData = new Vector();
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        Vector tmp = (Vector) data.get(i);
        Vector nVc = new Vector();
        for (int j = 0; j < tmp.size(); j++) {
            nVc.addElement(tmp.get(j));
        }
        defData.add(nVc);
    }
    return defData;
}

}
```

This will work but it's not good practice, you should run the code that deals with the interface on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) and the other part (file reading, vector creation) on another thread.

Comment: I have tried the above code but was not able to find a solution

Comment: @Rudy dev I've edited my answer, it should work now.

Comment: But after i modified the reading part it give me minor errors such as if i edit 2 cells of my table it refresh the last edited cell.can u please help me with it @Titus.

Comment: @Rudy dev That is probably because the first time you create the table model you're doing it like this `new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)` instead of `new DefaultTableModel(getDefaultData(), columnNames)`, take a better look at my code especially at the parts where the `DefaultTableModels` are created.

Comment: Thank you @Titus it worked.Can u please help i am making a ui in which i read data from file to different JComboboxes and i want a refresh button for it.can u please give me an idea of how to do it

Comment: @Rudy dev Try to do it yourself, you can start by reading [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)

Comment: can u please help me @Titus to refresh different combobox values.